# fetch response replaces Hebrew with question marks in black diamonds

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, node-fetch

```
 const fetch = require("node-fetch")

 fetch("https://www.example.com")
 .then(res => res.text())
 .then(data => console.log(data))
```

The output is HTML string, but Hebrew words replaced with ���� ����

How to set proper encoding to show Hebrew text properly? 
The final goal is to check whether multiple websites contain certain Hebrew keyword.

Comment: Can you provide an example URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default (`res.text()`) assumes utf8 has been used, but, as pointed out by [this issue](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/184), it's not always the case. That *might* be your case, in which case you might want to try replacing `res.text()` by [`res.textConverted()`](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch#bodytextconverted) so as to perform encoding sniffing before converting to a string.